# Monitoring remote servers with Nagios

Tags: monitoring, remote-server, nagios

I try to checking state of some devices, but they are not available from Nagios server. So I tried to use other server with NSClient++. Thus on Nagios I created file `/etc/configs/templates.cfg` with content:

```
define command{
        command_name    check-host-alive-dpi
        command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe -H 192.168.112.12 -c remote_ping -a $HOSTADDRESS$
        }


define host{
    name                    DPI ; The name of this host template
    use                     generic-host    ; This template inherits other values from the generic-host template
    check_period            24x7        ; By default, Linux hosts are checked round the clock
    check_interval          5       ; Actively check the host every 5 minutes
    retry_interval          1       ; Schedule host check retries at 1 minute intervals
    max_check_attempts      10      ; Check each Linux host 10 times (max)
    check_command           check-host-alive-dpi ; Default command to check Linux hosts
    notification_period     24x7
    notification_interval   120     ; Resend notifications every 2 hours
    notification_options    d,u,r       ; Only send notifications for specific host states
    #contact_groups         admins,zikit        ; Notifications get sent to the admins by default
    hostgroups              przystanki
    register                0       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL HOST, JUST A TEMPLATE!
    }
```

Next I defined hosts in `/servers/DPI.cfg` file, which looks like that:

```
   define host{
    use     DPI
    host_name   cc01
    alias       cc01, ethernet
    address     172.18.5.85
    parents     KRKttl01
    }

define host{
    use     DPI
    host_name   cc02
    alias       cc02, ethernet
    address     172.18.5.86
    parents     KRKttl01
    }

define host{
    use     DPI
    host_name   cc03
    alias       cc03, ethernet
    address     10.0.54.16
    parents     KRKttl01
    }
```

When I restart Nagios it can't get up. It say:

```
Failed to start LSB:starts and stops the Nagios monitoring server.
```

I did not change/create any other files.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What can you find in nagios.log?
Also, try run config check before you restart Nagios server via `nagios -v /path/to/main/nagios/config.cfg`

Comment: Now it's ok there were duplicated hosts and it was a reason. Thanks for your commitment.